# Configuring my email MX record

Tags: server, dns, email, postfix

I'm dropping my hosting and email service with GoDaddy. I will maintain them as my registrar and DNS. I have setup an Ubuntu Linux 14.04.3 Apache2 web server and it is working. I just need to open the port and point my domain to my IP address. In addition I have another server running the same OS and Postfix/Dovecot.

My issue is with naming my email server and pointing the GoDaddy MX record to it. At this point the email server hostname is 'server' and the web server hostnamed is 'devrod.com'. I've read so much online I'm thoroughly confused. Will someone please guide me through the process of getting my MX record configured properly?

Comment: Correction: the web server name is 'secure' and the email server is 'devrod.com"

Comment: Ha, I am doing the exact same thing, and flamed out on the email.  Looking forward to see if you get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Say your domain name is `example.com` and your webserver (secure) IP address is `1.2.3.4` and your email server (devrod.com) IP address is `5.6.7.8` then you can set the following records.

```
;MX record for example.com
example.com. some_ttl IN      MX    some_priority  mail.example.com

; A record for mail.example.com
mail.example.com.   some_ttl IN  A   5.6.7.8

; A record for example.com
example.com.   some_ttl IN  A   1.2.3.4
```

**PS:** Your system name has nothing to do with your `MX` records or `A` records. But make sure that you set your `myhostname` properly in your `main.cf` so that postfix need not guess it's name from system name.

Comment: OK, well as with answering a question another pops up. In you example above you use

Comment: EDIT: Maybe I should have mentions I have 2 servers that have only 1 Internet facing IP address. In you example above you use "IP address is 1.2.3.4" and IP address is 5.6.7.8". Are you referring to LAN addresses or Internet addresses? The later I understand but, why would internal IPA's be pertinent. Would not that routing be handles at the router with port forwarding? Sorry, maybe several questions, but the PS was very helpful, Thank you!